# HTML5 video player showing to enable flash in browser. How can I play stream video without enable the flash?

Tags: html, flash, video, video-streaming, television

I made a streaming server and a website to show the Video. I have tried with many HTML5 player. But problem is no player working without enable flash on browser. There are a website http://jagobd.com and its playing video even I block flash on this site. How they did it? and How can I get this kind of player open source? could you please give me any solution?

Comment: My streaming link is Rtmp and I tried with HDW player, VideoJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My streaming link is Rtmp

RTMP is a Flash technology, and only plays in Flash or other players that support it.  No browser supports RTMP, and it's unlikely that any will in the future.

If you want to use a regular HTML5 player, you need to use a compatible streaming format.  Consider DASH.  While it doesn't have native support in-browser, it doesn't need it as it can be handled with MediaSource Extensions.  Most modern browsers support MSE.  Many encoders do as well, and you can use whatever static web hosting or CDN you want.

There are other options for video distribution as well, if you have special streaming requirements.

Comment: If I use DASH, enable flash from browser is not required?

Comment: @MdSabbirAhmed Correct.